# Gzip compression in multiple files

Tags: php

I am using Vanilla 2 forum and i noticed that my host does not support gzip.
I also noticed that in the php info file gzip is enabled.
So what i am trying to do is to put this line of code:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

at the very first line after the php tags. But there are almost 1000 php files in the whole vanilla script. Is there a way to automate this?
Or is there another alternative to gzip my website?

**Update:**

My .htaccess file:

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

Comment: Has your host mod_gzip installed and activated?

Comment: no also not. They do not support that

Comment: I guess `auto_prepend_file` is also not activated, is it? Well, the last option would be to add the line to all PHP files using a script (bash, PowerShell, ...).

Comment: Have you asked your host if they can enable it? There is no reason, that I can think of, not to support it. Sure, it will add a little CPU overhead, but conversely it will reduce bandwidth usage.

Comment: Why would you have to start ob_gzhandler in every include script? If there's a router/dispatcher/index.php for the board. Just add it once there.

Comment: well i did the following: i put some lines in my .htaccess file to force apache to gzip compress. That works, i have tested it on http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php. (see .htaccess in my update above). There is only one thing: testing on Gmetrix.com it says that i could increase performance when i also compress .less files. But how can i compress a .less file with a line of code in my .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

There's the [auto_prepend_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive, which lets you force a particular chunk of code to be prependted to every file. You could put the `ob` code into that file, point PHP's prepend at it, and boom, gz output on all the scripts.